# Convert downloaded image to png/jpeg from bitmap, and display in imageView - Android

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I currently have the below code, which goes to a specified URL, pulls down whatever image is there, converts it to a bitmap and then display's it in an imageView.

However, I have noticed that when I am scrolling through my listView which contains these bitmaps; the scrolling has gone jerky (as multiple bitmap's are being renderd).

My question is. How would I, given the below code, convert the downloaded bitmap into a png/jpeg format and display that in an imageView? So that the listView's scrolling will no longer be jerky.

I do not want to save it to a file and then load that file from the phone, as there could potentially be 100+ images being downloaded at one time.

The bitmap code:

```
//This downloads the image from thr url passed, and converts into a bitmap format; so that android compilers can read it and then display it.
private Bitmap GetImageBitmapFromUrl(string url)
{
    Bitmap imageBitmap = null;

    // bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); //100-best quality

    using (var webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        var imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(url);
        if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0)
        {
            imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);                   
        }
    }

    return imageBitmap;
}
```

How I am binding it to the imageView:

```
var imageBitmap = GetImageBitmapFromUrl(item.imgURL);
view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.Image).SetImageBitmap((Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(imageBitmap, 100, 100, false)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I've played around loooooooooads with this trying to make it work efficiently, I've still not found a good enough solution other than to save them all. Basically, you could try save em all then maybe set up a delete after the render has happened, or maybe after all images have been rendered? I keep all the images on my sd card but they're only like 100kb each but I do have like 400 of them per 'usage', but still that's only 40mb on a 8gb sd card.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. Right ok, so the only viable way is to save them; that's a bummer. When you save them, can you save them into a local app directory folder so that the user can't access them. Or do you have to save them to their local images folder?

Comment: I just save onto the SD card under the name of my company and in a dir under the app name. so yeah, it's not that protected but I doubt a user would go through that sort of stuff. you should have a little look at displaying your bitmaps efficiently though cause my bitmaps come in at 1280 and they are still high quality on a tablet at 320*180 so it's a real waste of memory to display them in high res. if you just follow the steps in here it'll help you loads http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: I just read the last line of your code, I don't think that is doing what you think it's doing. That is I believe is the equivalent of opening the bitmap, then creating a new one from it which is just creating sooooooo much more processing time than necessary. As I say, follow that link i said, it'll take you 30 min and you'll understand it loads

Answer (score 0):

The jerkiness of the images have nothing to do with what format you use to display them.  When you set an image into an ImageView, they are internally converted to Bitmaps anyway.  The core here is to ensure that you are not using images larger than you need.  For example, if your ImageView is 100x100 pixels wide and you're downloading an image that's 1000x1000 pixels, setting it into your ImageView would work for display purposes but it would use way too much memory.  Instead you should download the image, scale it to match the size of your ImageView, then recycle the original bitmap.

As the memory footprint is much smaller, the jerkiness will be much less noticeable.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. All of the images that I am downloading are pretty smallish anyways. Do you know if there is a way to reduce the quality if the bitmap maybe? And also, the line in my code above 'CreateScaledBitmap', is that not resizng it as you said, or is this doing something different?

Comment: @CallumHolden Yes, it's resizing, but you are not recycling the original bitmap - so you are effectively keeping two bitmaps in memory for each displayed image.